# Foreign key statement Error

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my statement:

```
CREATE TABLE course(
c_id VARCHAR(3),
c_name varchar(30),
room_number integer NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT fk_course FOREIGN KEY (room_number) REFERENCES
    building_room(room_number),
CONSTRAINT pk_course PRIMARY KEY (c_id), 
CONSTRAINT check_name CHECK (c_name <> NULL));
```

The error I get:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "building_room"

Comment: Show us the building_room definition. (Probably no primary key , or unique key, for room_number.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `check (c_name <> NULL)` is not going to work. You can't compare `NULL` with `<>`. You either need `c_name IS NOT NULL` or simply define the column as `NOT NULL` (as you did with `room_number`)

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint is a relationship between two tables, such that every row in the first table (child table) is related to a certain row in the second table (parent table). The relationship is implemented with one or more colums with the same values in the corresponding rows in both tables.

One key point here is that you have to be able to identify the matching row in a parent table. For that, you need a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column (or columns) on the parent table, because otherwise the row values would not uniquely identify a row in the parent table.

So you will need a `UNIQUE` constraint on `building_room(room_number)`.